# Where do you find Dark Sun Minis?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, miniatures, dark-sun

Apart from picking up the old 2ed Dark Sun miniatures off ebay, does anyone have any suggestions for a line of mini's that work well thematically for Dark Sun?

Perhaps a line of primitive or aztec fantasy minis.  Even some Conan ones might work.  I'm holding out hope that some obscure skirmisher game had a army of stone age style warriors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going in a slightly different direction.  Lego.
The Prince of Persia line of Legos has some very Dark Sun looking minis.  With a few alterations and some paint I got a very passable, all be it much less serious, miniature.  For reference, he's a voidsoul genasi swordmage.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes! An earlier question on this board brought up [Caesar miniatures](http://miniknight.com/caesar.htm) which makes several inexpensive (soft plastic, but still paintable) historical lines. They make several sets (including Inca and Mayan warriors, egyptians, etc)  that I think might work really well. Some of the romans and greeks and egyptians would work as well. Best thing about them is the price- usally $10-20 for an entire army of 30 or 40 figures. Check the links out below for some samples.

THESE guys would make excellent Dark Sun-esque figures. Maybe glue on some more spikes.

- http://miniknight.com/images/gallery/G88/philistinethomas.jpg
- http://miniknight.com/images/gallery/G89/ancientegyptianwarriorsthomas.JPG
- http://miniknight.com/images/gallery/G85/sherdenpoland.jpg

Best way to order is from one of the hobby shops listed in their "where to buy" section- they apparently don't sell direct.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a popular (and unsatisfactorily answered) topic on various forums. There are a lot of suggestions, but nothing that's more than "kinda close".

Though, it's worth noting that messing about with eBay auctions isn't the only source of the original Ral Partha Dark Sun miniatures line. [Tome of Treasures](http://tomeoftreasures.com/tot_second_edition_home/2E_darksun_minis.htm) has a nice selection of them for reasonable prices that don't appear to be much more than the original MSRP. Of course, those are all metal and unpainted, which may be another reason to pass on the old AD&D minis.